# Extensible object which doesn't allow existing properties to be changed?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript objects can be sealed, which prevents new properties from being added and existing properties from being removed or reconfigured, but the properties remain writable. They can also be frozen, which is sealed plus all properties become non-writable.

Conspicuously absent is the ability to make the existing properties read-only, non-removable, non-configurable while leaving the object extensible. This would be useful to prevent accidental trampling on an object's properties while allowing other code to augment it's properties.

What's the best or idiomatic way to create such an object using vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop through the object's properties and make each one non-writable and non-configurable:

```
var obj = { "foo": 1, "bar": 3 };
Object.defineProperty(obj, "baz", { set: a=>a });

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(name) {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, name);
    desc.configurable = false;

    // make the property non-writable if it is not an accessor property
    if(!desc.set && !desc.get) { desc.writable = false; }

    Object.defineProperty(obj, name, desc);
});
```

Note that this doesn't make accessor properties defined by `set` and `get` methods "non-writable" since the notion of writability doesn't apply to an accessor property -- storing into an accessor property runs the setter.

Comment: Firefox seems to leave "value" alone if it's not mentioned.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I learned recently that `defineProperty` has different behaviors for defining new properties versus modifying existing properties. though now that you mention it, I should add a `try`/`catch` to handle some odd cases -- apparently an extant `set` slot and `configurable: false` together do not play nicely when trying to do `configurable: false` a second time.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that now... I always get confused by the name `defineProperty` because to me it indicates the creation of a completely new property (blowing away everything that exists).

Comment: Or directly use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` (plural 's'): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors . *edit:* Or not since it returns an object instead of an array. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1):

For instance you could use a getter to set your properties like:

```
var object = {get property(){return "value"} };
```

making them read only, meaning you can't change its value by assignment anymore as in:

```
 object.property = "other";
```

since it has no setter. So `object.property` will continue to return "value", but you can still delete the 'property' key using the `delete`operator.

Comment: This still allows the property to be overwritten by `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: you don't have to go all the way in using the awkward Object.definePropertty syntax to do that - (because as already mentioned you can easily delete it and assign a fresh one) in the original no b.s old way for that matter - but in case you want your properties safe from being accidentally assigned a different value - than the given syntax will do and will hold up very well.